# Preprocessing on propensity score matched data

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, propensity-scores

I did preprocessing, then propensity score matching using logistic regression, and then fit a glm to the response variable of interest. However, the odds ratio obtained was 0.0008 (while it should be about .5 to .7 ish). I then tried preprocessing **on the matched data** and got an odds ratio of .7 ish and a ROC curve that was better than guessing. Is this valid or does it mess up the covariate balance obtained from propensity score matching, if I do **preprocessing on the matched dataset**? That is, standardizing the columns, removing columns with high collinearity, and removing near-constant variance columns. Thanks.